# Allow Anonymous Users to Access Specific URLs in Orchard CMS

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, orchardcms

I have a custom module that uses a Routes.cs and AdminController.cs file to define a new url route and action to be taken but it can only be accessed when a user is logged in. I have tried adding the [Authorize] and [AllowAnonymous] attributes in my AdminController.cs file and I have tried including the following in my Web.config file:

```
 <location path="/speedbump">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="?"/>
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
```

Neither of these methods appear to work. How do I go about making sure this url can be accessed by all users/visitors to the site and not just those who are logged in? Thank you.

Routes.cs File:

```
public class Routes : IRouteProvider
    {
        public void GetRoutes(ICollection<RouteDescriptor> routes)
        {
            foreach (var routeDescriptor in GetRoutes())
                routes.Add(routeDescriptor);
        }

        public IEnumerable<RouteDescriptor> GetRoutes()
        {
            return new[] {
                new RouteDescriptor {
                    Priority = 15,
                    Route = new Route(
                        "speedbump",
                        new RouteValueDictionary {
                            {"area", "Speedbump"},
                            {"controller", "Admin"},
                            {"action", "isValidURL"}
                        },
                        new RouteValueDictionary(),
                        new RouteValueDictionary {
                            {"area", "Speedbump"}
                        },
                        new MvcRouteHandler())
                }
            };
        }
    }
```

AdminController.cs File:

```
[Authorize]
    public class AdminController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [AllowAnonymous]
        public void isValidURL()
        {
            string requestedURL = Request.QueryString["url"];
            //Create a list of strings to contain all the "valid" URLs
            var whiteList = new List<string>();
            //Add URLs to the list
            whiteList.Add("www.google.com");

            foreach (string validURL in whiteList)
            {
                if (requestedURL == validURL)
                {
                    Response.Write("Speedbump");
                    //Response.Redirect(requestedURL);

                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: If you want everyone to access use <allow users="*"/>

Comment: That didn't work either, is there a specific place in the Web.config file that it needs to be?

Comment: Anywhere before the authentication tag. can you paste that authentication tag section ?

Comment: Also try having a ~ before path.
<location path="~/speedbump">

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use `AdminController` for that, create another controller called `AnythingelseController`. Admin controller is for admin stuff. It basically adds the Admin filter to that controller so users trying to access actions in that controller need the AccessAdminPanel permission.

If you want some pages in that controller to be admin and some to be anonymous themed pages create your controller `MyController` then decorate admin methods with `[Admin]` and anonymous themed methods with `[Themed]`.